# Easiest way to add subtitles

Tags: video-editor, subtitles

I'm tasked with translating and putting hard subtitles on dozens of videos. This is the only thing I will be doing to the videos and I have 0 experience with video editing. I am a programmer though. What's the most productive process/apps to accomplish this (just downloaded Lightworks)? Most video editing software can do this but isn't exactly optimized for this specific thing.

Right now I'm thinking about using a dedicated subtitle app to create softsubs and then ffmpeg to apply it to video? But as someone who's never done this before it seems easier to use the timeline function of video editors when creating the subs? Any advice please?

Answer (score 2):

For subtitle timing, I would suggest [Aegisub](https://unanimated.github.io/timing-basics.htm) and save the subtitles file as *.srt, then you can add the subtitles and export your video with [ActivePresenter](https://atomisystems.com/tutorials/ap8/add-closed-captions-activepresenter-8/)